# How to destroy Jquery UI spinner on blur

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

Hello guys i had textboxes and i want them to be a spinner when focused and to be the textbox when blur
this is my code

```
$(".spinner").focus(function () {
    $(this).spinner();
});

$(".spinner").blur(function () {
    $(this).spinner("destroy");
});
```

demo
http://jsfiddle.net/ygyogba0/

but im getting an error of "Cannot read property 'replaceWith' of undefined"

can anyone help me with this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me in chrome and IE11. It seems that the spinner widget was not setting focus after it's create. Using "On" is a great practice esp if you start doing partial postbacks. However, in firefox it was not setting the focus even with the extra call. This is an issue discussed at length in forums. If you need FF you will have to deal with that.

However, The FF issue is only an issue if the user never clicks in the spinner. I am not sure this solution is ready for prod.

```js
$("body").on("focus", ".spinner", function () {
$(this).spinner({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).focus();
        // Trying (and failing) to deal with FF
        /*setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).focus()
        }, 10); */
    }
});

});

$("body").on("blur", ".spinner", function () {
$(this).spinner("destroy");
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" class="spinner" /><br>
<input type="text" class="spinner" /><br>
<input type="text" class="spinner" /><br>
<input type="text" class="spinner" /><br>
```

Comment: Thanks men, please let me know if youve found a solution for firefox browser. I'll post one if i found it too.

Thanks

Comment: Great, The FF solution will make this a more complete answer. I am resisting the urge to make a Darth Vader with FF Meme "I find your lack of .Focus() disturbing"

Comment: Yeah that would be cool :), but one more thing i found is im still getting an error, any idea why is that ?

Cannot read property 'replaceWith' of undefined

Comment: Do you get it in more than one browser? Is that running the code embedded here? If not we may need a new question and some problem code.

Comment: Yes its your snippet im testing, open your console and click on the textbox,   you will see a message "Cannot read property 'replaceWith' of undefined"

Comment: Yes, im uncomfortable with the console errors even though its doing good :)

Comment: Even with the plain $(this).spinner(); you get that message when creating in the click. I wonder if a more recent jQueryui would be the fix.